Weil restriction of a bunch of points or more general disjoint unions
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$For a finite extension of fields $k'/k$, let $R_{k'/k}$ denote the Weil restriction functor from quasiprojective $k'$-schemes to quasiprojective $k$-schemes, defined as the right adjoint to the base change functor $X\mapsto X\times_k k'$. One way to think about it is by Galois descent; for an exposition see for example Thm 1.4 of Ji, Li, McFadden, Moore, and Stevenson - Weil restriction for schemes and beyond.
Question: I would like to understand what $R_{k'/k}(X')$ is if $X'$ has a stratification into locally closed $k'$-subschemes $X'=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^r X'_i$. You could attach any niceness assumptions to the stratification if it helps.
===This is the end of the TLDR version===
This at first sounds easy or standard, but I could not find references that treat this aspect, and it is actually subtle!
Now we dive in with more context and details. Look at the simplest case where $X'=\coprod_i X'_i$ is a coproduct (i.e., a topological disjoint union, meaning each $X'_i$ is open and closed in $X$). Then look at the simplest case of this simplest case, namely, $X'_i$ is a point $\Spec(k')$. In other words, $X'$ is just $r$ points. Using Galois descent it is not hard to see for quadratic $k'/k$ (you could take $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$):
$$R_{k'/k}(\Spec (k') \sqcup \Spec(k'))\simeq \Spec(k')\sqcup \Spec(k)\sqcup \Spec(k),$$
while $R_{k'/k}(\Spec(k'))\simeq \Spec(k)$. For quadratic extension but for more general schemes, one could get (again from descent)
$$R_{k'/k}(X'_1\sqcup X'_2)=R_{k'/k}(X'_1) \sqcup R_{k'/k} (X'_2) \sqcup (X'_1\times_{k'} X'_2)$$
where the last scheme is viewed as a $k$-scheme by composing with the structural morphism $\Spec(k')\to \Spec(k)$. This is obtained from expanding out $(X'_1\sqcup X'_2)\times (X'_1\sqcup X'_2)$, getting four terms, and keeping track of how the Galois acts. (Basically, it permutes the two direct factors with a "twist".)
But the complexity seems to blow up when there are more terms in the disjoint union, and when the Galois group is more complicated. Say $X'$ is three points $P_1\sqcup P_2\sqcup P_3$ over $k'$, and $[k':k]=3$ is an $S_3$-extension. Then if we fix the labeling of three $k$-embeddings $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3:k'\to \bar{k}$, we can recognize $R_{k'/k}(X')$ as a descent datum on the $\bar{k}$-scheme $\bar{X'}\times \bar{X'}\times \bar{X'}$. We then recognize some of components of $R_{k'/k}(X')$ (as a $k$-scheme), such as
$$Y_{112} \times_k \bar{k}:=P_1\times P_1\times P_2 \sqcup P_1\times P_2\times P_1 \sqcup P_2\times P_1\times P_1,$$
and
$$Y_{123}\times_k \bar{k}:=\coprod_{\sigma\in S_3} P_{\sigma(1)}\times P_{\sigma(2)}\times P_{\sigma(3)}.$$
Is there a systematic way to recognize the $k$-scheme structures of these? (My guess: you just get $\Spec (\smash{\bar{k}}^H)$ where $H$ is a suitable stabilizer. But I can't get the details straight.) What if $P_i$ are replaced by affine spaces of various dimensions?

Do you mean to assume (as your reference to Galois descent suggests) that $k'/k$ is separable?

If you think of the Weil restriction as a relative Hilbert scheme (a la FGA), then the partition of $X’$ induces a partition of the closed subscheme.  If $k’/k$ is separable of degree $n$ equal to the full symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$, that is probably the best you can do: a partition of the Hilbert scheme into locally closed subschemes based on the corresponding partition of ${ 1,\dots,n}.$

@LSpice Yes. To add more: by Theorem 2.8 of http://www.shizhang.li/weil_restriction.pdf, Weil restriction along purely inseparable field extension commutes with disjoint union (at least the coproduct case), so the hard part of the original question lies in the separable case.

@JasonStarr This is a great suggestion! I wasn't aware of the relative Hilbert scheme viewpoint before. After some reading I have some vague ideas but am still confused: which relative Hilbert scheme is it exactly, i.e., does Weil restriction $R_{k'/k}(X')$ parametrize closed subschemes of something? Is there a pushforward in this picture?

Let $G \subset S_n$ be the Galois group of the Galois closure of $k'/k$. Then you get a stratification whose components are parametrized by the G-orbits of the set ${1, \dots, r}^n$ (where G acts by permuting the $n$ entries). This is exactly what you find if you carry out the descent procedure given in the second part of your answer. Each component is given by applying descent to the union of the corresponding strata over $\bar{k}$ where Weil restriction is just a product.

Anyway, I do not think this is the best way to think of this situation.  Instead you should think of $R_{k′/k}(X′)$ as being a variety over $k$ such that $R_{k′/k}(X′)_{\overline{k}}$ has a stratification with whatever niceness properties you need. And the stratification is compatible with the Galois action.

@TimSantens I see. Now it is clearer to me that we can safely zoom in on each stratum. But I feel that I am missing something basic about Galois descent in general to recognize each stratum. For example, if r=2, all X_i' are affine A^1, n=3, G=S_3, and the G-orbit is the multiset {1,1,2}, then is there a simple description of this stratum?

If $G = S_n$ and the $G$-orbit is ${1,1,2}$ then I believe the result of the descent is as follows. Let $L/k'$ be the Galois closure, the stratum is $R_{L/k'} (X'1)L \times{k'} (X_2){k'}$ considered as a $k$-scheme. So if the $X'i$ are $\mathbb{A}^1$ then this is just $\mathbb{A}^3{k'}$. To do the descent you use that the stabilizer $C_2$ acts the same as it does for the descent of the Weil restriction $R_{L/k'}$. I guess with some more effort one could get similar descriptions if $G = S_n$ for all orbits. For general $G$ the combinatorics seems too complicated.
